# Command prompt says I have no Microsoft Word files?

Tags: windows-7, command-line, microsoft-word

I opened a command window and typed `dir *.docx` at the prompt. The command did not find any files. However, I have 3 Microsoft word files in My Documents.

This confuses me. I tried other experiments with analyzing word files through the command prompt, and the system doesn't acknowledge them.

Answer (score 6):

Try `dir *.doc*`. Also make sure that your command prompt is looking in the correct folder. Remember that it does not look in sub folders.

Comment: And if this still doesn't yield any results, just type `dir` to see all files. It usually tells you if you are in the right folder or not. `dir /p` can be used to give you a prompt when the output exceeds the height of the page, so you can see everything.

Answer (score 0):

Check to make sure the files are visible?

```
cd /D "%UserProfile%\Documents"
attrib /s *.docx
```